# Unicode characters for line drawing or box drawing

Tags: c

Hello I use following code to print tabulated out put of my database queries

```
printf("+----------+------------+\n");
printf("|  Col1    |  Col2      |\n);
printf("+----------+------------+\n");
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
   printf("|%8s|%8s|\n",str1,str2);
printf("+----------+------------+\n");
```

It just makes my db tables look good. But can any one suggest me a more decorative way.
Can I use unicode characters to make it more appealing.

Comment: curses http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library)

Comment: Unicode support depends on your compiler and OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unicode does include some characters intended for this.  Wikipedia has a list:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character

Answer (score 2):

You can use Curse (ncurses) library for this, or take a look at my project: libtprint - a simple library to print tabled data, https://github.com/wizzard/libtprint

Hope it helps !

Comment: May be you could make it better by using box drawing charcter set as mentioned in above answer

Comment: thank you for pointing, will definitely extend my library ! (feel free to add "feature" request to github page if you are going to use it).